# Thingsboard 3 Export Chart to Image

Tags: image, charts, export, thingsboard

Please tell me how can I export a chart to image in Thingsboard 3 or
how to copy it to clipboard memory !

Thank You !

Answer (score 0):

Take a screenshot.

On Windows it should be enough to press the <kbd>Print</kbd> button on your keyboard.
Windows should capture the whole screen and save it as an image to the clipboard.
You can open your favorite image editor to paste and cut out the chart.